# Stack Exchange site copy

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

I probably found a case of plagiarism of Stack Exchange code (i.e. a site that's probably powered by Stack Exchange scripts). I don't know how its authors found the script(s), and I don't know if it really is Stack Exchange code, so please check. The site is http://devpytania.pl/ (it's in Polish).

Comment: Wow moderators there [have two diamonds](http://meta.devmedia.pl/users/4/rafek/)!!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd if I recall correctly, two diamonds = site owner, one diamond = appointed moderator.

Comment: @Pop no single diamond [here](http://meta.devmedia.pl/users/?sort=last).. weird!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd why bother appointing a mod when you already have a skeet there?

Answer (score 7):

That would be a StackExchange 1.0 site. Before Area51 ([StackExchange 2.0](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/04/changes-to-stack-exchange/)), people could have their own StackExchange sites.

Comment: Actually it's a SE 1.0 with a theme that doesn't make me want to fork my eyes out! There aren't many like that.