# IS this an extreme copy of Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, copycat-sites

I just came across http://answers.splunk.com/

Not only is the UI similar to Stack Exchange, but they have *identical* badges and even *diamond mods*. (The biggest difference I see is that they have karma, whereas we have rep)

1. Is this [SE 1.0](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/82492/202832), or a knock-off?
2. If it is, indeed, a knock-off, will SE take legal action?

Comment: Clones aplenty: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-exchange-clones And I don't immediately see anything that's a problem.

Comment: "Engage with the Splunk community on Splunkbase and learn how to get the most out of your Splunk deployment." - copyright **2005** ... that's 9 years now.. and the 2.0 changes were in 2010. Now that's a huge gap there...

Comment: No, SE never takes actions against clones. Q&A is not a SE invention.. That site is *not* a SE 1.0 site, it is just another clone.

Comment: Splunk uses Answerhub, see http://answerhub.com/customers/. Answerhub is listed on the clones question.